# Reliable exit from bash function on error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling

So I learned that `set -e` has no effect inside Bash functions and one needs to combine `set -o errexit` with a `trap` to automatically exit from within a function in case an error occurs. Unfortunately this does not seem to work if a function is called within an if statement or when combined with `&&` or `||`.

Let's say I set up error handling like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -o errtrace
trap 'rc=$?; echo "ERROR catched."; exit $rc' ERR

function myfunc() {
  bad_command
  echo "SUCCESS!"
}
```

I get the following desired results:

```bash
myfunc
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
ERROR catched.

myfunc | cat
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
ERROR catched.

a=$(myfunc)
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
ERROR catched.
```

and these undesired results:

```bash
myfunc || true
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
SUCCESS!

myfunc && true
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
SUCCESS!

if myfunc; then true; fi
test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
SUCCESS!
```

How can I ensure that execution within a function is always aborted ow matter how the function is executed?

Comment: What do you mean by `set -e` does not work?

Comment: Anyway, I suspect you are faced with a version of [this standard pitfall](https://github.com/coq-community/docker-coq-action/#pitfall-do-not-use--use-semicolons)

Comment: `set -e` works as documented. That doesn't mean it works as intended or expected. Don't use `set -e` in place of your own error handling.

Comment: The idea here is that if you don't want to exit when `myfunc` has a non-zero exit status, you don't want it to abort early, either.

Comment: If you want to be sure to exit, you should write `bad_command || exit 1`.  Anything else is a subtle bug waiting to happen.  (And even this is a bug waiting to happen, since the function can be called in a subshell)

Comment: But...do you want to "exit from within a function" as stated, or do you just want to return from the function?  If the latter, write the function as `bad_command || return 1`.  Explicit error handling is your friend.

Comment: Invalid use of `set -e` is one of the pitfalls of learning bash.  Another pitfall is paying attention to the people that suggest you should use it.  Don't.  Throw it in the rubbish bin.  Never use it.  It makes scripts more difficult to understand and causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c.f. the [trap documentation](https://ss64.com/bash/trap.html), specifically -

> If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a simple command has a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions. **The ERR trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of a && or || list**, or if the command's return value is being inverted via !.

You were on the right track with `errtrace`, but ERR traps are ignored when there's already a condition test on the command.

From the [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) Functions page -

> All other aspects of the shell execution environment are identical between a function and its caller with these exceptions: the DEBUG and RETURN traps are not inherited unless the function has been given the trace attribute using the declare builtin or the -o functrace option has been enabled with the set builtin, (in which case all functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps), and the ERR trap is not inherited unless the -o errtrace shell option has been enabled. See Bourne Shell Builtins, for the description of the trap builtin.

So you can bypass this with `functrace` and manually checking with the DEBUG option if you want.

```
set -o functrace
trap 'rc=$?; if ((rc)) then echo "ERROR $rc caught."; exit $rc; fi' debug
```

Skip the `set -e`, but understand `exit` is aborting the script, not just returning from the function.